# TSQL datediff issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I just found using real data that

```
datediff(SECOND, TimeStart, TimeEnd) / 60
```

is not the same as

```
datediff(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd)
```

I used this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, TimeStart, TimeEnd) AS seconds, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, TimeStart, TimeEnd) / 60 AS Mins1,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd) AS Mins2
```

and I'm getting these results:

```
seconds   mins1   mins2
-------------------------
  236        3       4
  620       10      10
  536        8       9
  443        7       8
  692       11      12
 1038       17      18   
  SUM       56      61
```

Can anyone explain it?

What is the correct approach to get minutes difference in T-SQL between two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql):

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

The issue is that users *want* the function to do something else.  As a consequence, the number of years between 2016-12-31 23:59:59 and 2017-01-01 00:00:01 is 1 year -- even though the date/time values are 2 seconds apart.

This is one reason why experienced users of `datediff()` choose the smallest reasonable unit available (seconds or milliseconds) and then derive the higher units from that.  Alas, this doesn't work for months, but it does work for most units.

Comment: Ok, gotcha but what do excactly I have to use `datediff(SECOND, TimeStart, TimeEnd)/60 `  or `datediff(MINUTE, TimeStart, TimeEnd)` ?

Comment: It depends what you want to calculate.  I think the first is more accurate, particularly if you divide by `60.0`, so you are not just doing integer arithmetic.